Flutter shadermask or cliprect widget problem? Adding gradient to a specific area
I am trying to make a habit tracker page. My logic is that I get a habit from the user. I get totaldays. I encounter problems when I want to show this. The shader mask widget did not help.
import 'package:best_version_of_yourself/features/2_progres_screen/habit_provider.dart';
import 'package:best_version_of_yourself/util/app_sizes.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class TodoText54 extends StatefulWidget {
  const TodoText54({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    required this.completedDays,
    required this.totalDays,
    required this.index,
  });

  final String text;
  final int completedDays;
  final int totalDays;
  final int index;

  @override
  State<TodoText54> createState() => _TodoTextState();
}

class _TodoTextState extends State<TodoText54> {
  bool isDone = false;
  late int localCompletedDays;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    localCompletedDays = widget.completedDays;
  }

  void _changeStatus() {
    setState(() {
      isDone = !isDone;

      if (isDone) {
        // Gün tamamlanınca completedDays sayısını artırıyoruz
        localCompletedDays += 1;
        Provider.of<HabitProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .updateHabit(widget.index, localCompletedDays);
      } else {
        // Eğer tamamlanma geri alındıysa completedDays sayısını azaltıyoruz
        if (localCompletedDays > 0) {
          localCompletedDays -= 1;
          Provider.of<HabitProvider>(context, listen: false)
              .updateHabit(widget.index, localCompletedDays);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final habit = Provider.of<HabitProvider>(context).habits[widget.index];

    return Row(
      children: [
        // Ana container genişliği ve yüksekliği ayarlandı
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            height: AppSizes.screenHeight / 15,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
              color: Colors.transparent, // Arka plan tamamen şeffaf
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: List.generate(widget.totalDays, (index) {
                return Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0), // Kutular arası boşluk
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8), // Kutuların yuvarlak köşeleri
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          // Tamamlanmamış günler gri renkli olur
                          Container(
                            height: AppSizes.screenHeight / 15,
                            color: Colors.grey.shade400, // Başlangıçta gri
                          ),
                          // ShaderMask sadece tamamlanan günlerde gradient uygular
                          if (index < localCompletedDays)
                            ShaderMask(
                              shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
                                return LinearGradient(
                                  colors: [
                                    Colors.green.shade200,
                                    Colors.green.shade300,
                                    Colors.green.shade400,
                                    Colors.green.shade500,
                                    Colors.green.shade600,
                                    Colors.green.shade700,
                                  ],
                                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                ).createShader(bounds);
                              },
                              blendMode: BlendMode.srcATop, // Sadece iç kısmı renklendirir
                              child: Container(
                                height: AppSizes.screenHeight / 15,
                                color: Colors.white, // Gradient etkisi burada görünür
                              ),
                            ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
            ),
          ),
        ),

        // Sağ tarafta bağımsız tik butonu
        IconButton(
          onPressed: _changeStatus,
          icon: AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            child: isDone
                ? Icon(
                    Icons.check_box,
                    key: ValueKey<bool>(isDone),
                    color: Colors.green,
                    size: 28,
                  )
                : Icon(
                    Icons.check_box_outline_blank_outlined,
                    key: ValueKey<bool>(isDone),
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    size: 28,
                  ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


enter image description here
I don't want this gradient to be visible outside the small gray boxes. I want to show the total number of gray boxes I received from the user side by side and lighten the color of the part of the graphite that falls on it each time it is completed.
ı try different variations shader mask and cliprect but ı couldnt figure out. enter image description here
ı am kinda expecting this

ı tried but didnt work, and my container is borderradius(16) so cliprect more usaable
